# boolean addition method seems to not work

Tags: java

When trying to print the result of copy() and add() the system prints 0s.
It works when deleting the m1 of m1.matrixArray[i][j] in both add() and copy().
But if deleting it seems to have conflict with the purpose of creating the instance as it is not being used.

Any idea on how to print the value?

```
public interface MatrixInterface {
    void makeEmpty(int m);
    boolean storeValue(int i, int j, int value);
    
    boolean add(MatrixInterface anotherMatrix);
    boolean copy(MatrixInterface anotherMatrix);
}

public class Matrix implements MatrixInterface{
    private int [][] matrixArray;
    private int dimension;
    
    public Matrix(int n){
        this.matrixArray = new int[n][n];
        this.dimension = n;
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public void makeEmpty(int m) {
        //check dimension - conditional statement
        if(m > dimension){
            m = dimension;
        }       
        for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<m; j++){
                matrixArray[i][j]=0;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean storeValue(int i, int j, int value) {
        if(i>=1 && i<= dimension && j>=1 && j<=dimension){
            matrixArray[i-1][j-1] = value;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(MatrixInterface anotherMatrix) {
        Matrix m1 = new Matrix(((Matrix) anotherMatrix).dimension);
        if(((Matrix) anotherMatrix).dimension == dimension){
            for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < dimension; j++) {
                    m1.matrixArray[i][j] =
                        matrixArray[i][j] + ((Matrix) anotherMatrix).matrixArray[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean copy(MatrixInterface anotherMatrix) {
        Matrix m1 = new Matrix(((Matrix) anotherMatrix).dimension);
        if(((Matrix) anotherMatrix).dimension == dimension){
        for(int i=0; i<dimension; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<dimension; j++){
                m1.matrixArray[i][j] = 
                        ((Matrix) anotherMatrix).matrixArray[i][j];
            }
        }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String outputStr = "";
        for(int i=0; i<dimension; ++i){
            for(int j=0; j<dimension; ++j){
                outputStr += String.format("%4d", matrixArray[i][j]);
            }
            outputStr += "\n";
        }
        
        return outputStr;
    }

}
```

Test class.

```
public class MatrixTest {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MatrixInterface matrix1 = new Matrix(2);
        MatrixInterface matrix2 = new Matrix(2);
        matrix1.makeEmpty(2);
        System.out.println(matrix1.toString());
        matrix1.storeValue(1,1,1);
        matrix1.storeValue(1,2,2);
        matrix1.storeValue(2,2,3);
        System.out.println(matrix1.toString());
        
        matrix2.add(matrix1);
        System.out.println(matrix2.toString());
        System.out.println(matrix2.add(matrix1));
        
        matrix2.copy(matrix1);
        System.out.println(matrix2.toString());
        System.out.println(matrix2.copy(matrix1));
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding and copying to a new Matrix. Hence the original Matrix `this` does not change. A Monday morning error.

Missing is the completeness of the interface:

```
public interface MatrixInterface {
    int getDimension();
    int retrieveValue(int i, int j);

public class Matrix implements MatrixInterface{
    @Override
    public int getDimension() {
        return dimension;
    }
```

A correct `add` then could be:

```
@Override
public boolean add(MatrixInterface anotherMatrix) {
    // Could do a partial add with:
    // int m = Math.min(dimension, anotherMatrix.getDimension());
    if (dimension != anotherMatrix.getDimension()) {
        return false; // Or:
        // throw IllegalArgumentException("Bounds not equal: "
        //     + dimension + " and " + anotherMatrix.getDimension());
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= dimension; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= dimension; j++) {
             storeValue(i, j, anotherMatrix.retrieveValue(i, j));
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

As you see, purely using the interface will make this method work with other implementations. There are diagonal matrices, where you might save many space, say a 100x100 matrix does not cost 10_000 but 5_050 ints. Or a sparse matrics where you might only store non-zero elements with their indices.

In fact as `add` does not use its class (when replacing `dimension` with `getDimension()`), just the interface you could move it to the interface as `default boolean add(MatrixInterface anotherMatrix) { ... }` - if you already treated default methods in interfaces.